# #<WeakSet> could not be cloned

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native application that I recently updated.
However, on the majority of my modules, I have this error:

`#<WeakSet> could not be cloned.`

For example, on the module : `@react-native-mapbox-gl`
When I launch my application, I get the error :

`node_modules\@react-native-mapbox-gl\maps\javascript\modules\snapshot\snapshotManager.js: #<WeakSet> could not be cloned.`

I also have it on my react-native-vector-icons module.

Is this a common problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with an internal module after updating from React Native 0.61 to 0.66.

Comment: Same error here. I've tried with different babel versions and I have still the same problem. I got it when I upgrade from RN 0.64.2 to 0.65.2.

Answer (score 0):

1. stop metro
2. reset repo
3. reinstall node_packages
4. run `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score -2):

Try deleting `node_modules` and reinstall with `npm install` or `yarn install` again, and then:

**IOS:**

1. `pod update SDWebImageWebPCoder`
2. `pod install --repo-update`
3. `build project in Xcode`

**Android:**

1. `Open in Android Studio` and `Refresh Gradle Dependencies`.
2. `build project in Android Studio`